# @wire(CurrentPageReference) pageRef returning null (LWC Component Embedded in Visual Force page)

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components

I am using the recipes "pubsub" folder in my components. They are working fine in LEX but when embedded into a VF page they run into the issue of pageRef not wiring. I am wondering if there is a work around.

The components in the VF page are embedded like so:

```
<div id="lightning" />

<script>
    $Lightning.use("c:lcvfTest", function() {
      $Lightning.createComponent("c:ComponentName",
          {},
          "lightning",
          function(cmp) {
            console.log("button was created");
            // do some stuff
          }
      );
    });
</script>
```

Components not referencing the pageRef have no issues.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation), this feature is only supported in:

> Lightning Experience, Lightning Communities, Salesforce Mobile App

You won't be able to use Lightning Navigation outside of a supported Salesforce framework.

The "workaround" would be to manually set a `window.location.href`. You won't be able to navigate using Lightning Navigation while in a VF page directly.